# Spoon lookup obtaining two rows instead of duplicate columns

Tags: etl, kettle, pentaho-spoon, spoon

I have this two tables

[image]

If I use the lookup step using the EMPLOYEEID and YEAR I get this columns:

[image]

But I need to get this instead:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have prepare a solution [Here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1jvUvKdBh_GkbKLTBqfSteubcPaNs_wKo?usp=sharing).
Using this you will get your result.

Please let me know if its ok with you.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. It's been a tough year. That's great, works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

A lookup is designed to retrieve fields from a matching  record in another table and append them to the "master" record.

If you want to combine records from 2 tables into a single dataset then you need to UNION them together.

**Update following comment**

Something like this pseudo-code ought to work:

```
SELECT T1.*
FROM TABLE1 T1
UNION
SELECT T2.*
FROM TABLE1 T2
INNER JOIN TABLE1 T1A ON T2.KEY1 = T1A.KEY1 AND T2.KEY2 = T1A.KEY2 AND ...
```

Comment: I tried with JOIN and UNION  but I need for each row, get a second row from the another table. I achieved that but I lost the transformation and I can't remember how I achieved it